# How can I keep the code output inside the PDF document, generated with RMarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown, margin, chunks

How can I keep the code generated in RMarkdown inside the margins of the document PDF generated?

[image]

Code:

```
url_IPI <- "https://www.idescat.cat/indicadors/?id=conj&n=10277&col=1&f=ssv"
destfile_IPI <- "G:/SUBDIRECCIO-ESTUDIS/PROJECTES/Automatitzar gràfics/Scripts R/Idescat/IPI.csv"
download.file(url_IPI, destfile_IPI)

IPI <- fread("G:/SUBDIRECCIO-ESTUDIS/PROJECTES/Automatitzar gràfics/Scripts R/Idescat/IPI.csv", header=TRUE, dec = ",", encoding = "UTF-8", na.strings = "..")
```

I've tried adding, in the chunk options, width=100% but it didn't work.

Comment: You could split your code aka the long file paths manually into or over multiple lines. That's what I would do even when working with scripts.

Comment: ok thanks, How can I do it?

Comment: Several Options. First. You could add a line break after a "," to split multiple arguments over multiple lines, e.g. in `fread`. Second, using this trick you also split you long file paths over multiple lines using e.g. `file.path("G:/SUBDIRECCIO-ESTUDIS/PROJECTES", "Automatitzar gràfics/Scripts R/Idescat/IPI.csv")` and then adding a line break after the "," separating the first and second part of the file path.